# PHP: a reasonable and lightweight way to store posts and user comments

Tags: php, json, database, storage

I'm developing an Instagram alike small corporate social networking site. There will be about 500-1000 posts, 5000-10000 comments in a year. Right now I implemented the posts part. The posts are stored in JSON file, where each post is represented with fields like "id", "date_time", "image_file", "description".

Now for the comments part. Each post can have a number of comments, so the most obvious way is to keep them in MySQL database. However, I don't like the hassle of configuring / initializing MySQL tables. I thought about storing comments in flat files (1 post in 1 file) but I have some concerns about concurrent writing issues.

Are there any other options? Based on your experience, what would you suggest?

Comment: sqlite  ..............

Comment: @zerkms, do I need to install some php / apache plugins to get it to work?

Comment: Just `pdo` (or any other client that you prefer more)

Comment: @zerkms, How does it compare to MySQL (in terms of speed, memory usage)?

Comment: It depends. There is no single correct answer to your question.

Comment: How about 1 word per file. Can there be a single wrong answer?

Comment: This question might get better answers at programmers.stackexchange.com.